# How to install java on a server managed by Cpanel?

Tags: java, linux, ssh, solr, cpanel

I am trying to get java installed on a server that I am running. I rented a server and domain from lithium hosting and I am trying to create a site on there that will be used to search files via solr. I am accessing the file system of the server through SSH on my Mac. I have install solr using wget and everything worked fine. However, I can not get java installed which is mandatory for solr to work. I have tried installed it using sudo, apt-get, yum and root@centos and all of those just return an error that those commands don't exist. I am able to download the appropriate tar.gz file using wget. but an error occurs whenever I try to run the command

```
tar xxx-xxx-xx.tar.gz
```

I get the error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The server is managed with a Cpanel account. How can I get java downloaded to the server. I need it for solr. Thanks

Comment: `tar.gz`, is not simply a tar. Add the `-z` flag to extract the gzip it first.

Comment: i.e. `tar -zxf xxx-xxx-xx.tar.gz`

Comment: I am getting the same error whenever including -zxf. Tried both the jdk and the server jre. Any other ideas? Is there a way to install Java from a way besides from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Decompress the tar.gz with the command:

`tar xzvf xxx-xxx-xx.tar.gz`

Comment: Hello, freedev. I have tried doing it the way you recommended and I am still getting the same error of: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
 Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: where have you downloaded the file `xxx-xxx-xx.tar.gz`? Had you tried to download the tar.gz file locally on your machine and tried to decompress? had you tried to download a new brand version of the tar.gz that may be corrupted during the first download?

Comment: I think I finally found it out. I was using wget and it was only partially downloading the tar.gz file. I downloaded on my machine and then used Filezilla to transfer it to the server and it let me tar it from there!

Comment: Finally :) i supposed that it could be corrupted during the first download... sometimes happens :/